# Meson: How to run tests that depend on an external process?

Tags: meson-build

I'm writing a meson.build file where I run several tests. These tests need a server running on a port in order to run successfully.

I started with this:

```
exe = executable('tests-client', 'tests-client.c')
test('test-client', suite: 'foo')
```

To run the tests I do:

```
$ meson test --suite foo
```

To launch the server, I run a script before the `test` call:

```
exe = executable('tests-client', 'tests-client.c')
run_command('start-server.sh')
test('test-client', suite: 'foo')
```

However, this doesn't work because `run_script` runs when meson builds, not when the tests are run. I also tried to run the server as if it was a test, but although it may work, it's semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to write a little script that starts the server and calls the test that is given as an argument. Then you can use Meson's [add_test_setup()](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#add_test_setup) with the kwarg `default: true`.

```
add_test_setup('server',                                         
  exe_wrapper: find_program('start-server-before-test.sh'),
  is_default: true,                                                
)
```

Comment: It didn't actually solve my particular issue, but I think it's due to my environment. It's a good solution. Thanks for sharing it.